# Calculate temperature of surroundings given heat source

Tags: electrical-engineering, thermodynamics

Im designing a miniature 8" x 8" x 8" burnout oven, and I want to estimate what temperature it will internally reach given a set voltage and current.

For reference, its heating element is 28AWG nichrome 80 wire [(specs here)](https://temcoindustrial.com/28-awg-1-lb-nichrome-80-resistance-wire/), it is insulated on each side with ceramic fiber [(specs here)](https://www.lynnmfg.com/wp-content/uploads/data/DATA-TC-514-205.pdf), and my power supply caps at 30V@10A.

I've done some (*potentially incorrect, im not an expert*) calculations beforehand to determine the maximum temperature the wire can attain by rewriting joules-law of wire heating, and setting it equal to a rewritten Stefan-Boltzmann Law, where the surface area of the radiator is instead that of a cylinder with radius of a 28AWG wire with unknown length. I figured if i could determine the point at which the rate of heat generated equaled the rate of heat lost, that would be the temperature the wire would settle at. I combined the equations above to obtain:

$$\frac{V^2}{\rho L} = \varepsilon  \sigma T^4 \cdot 2 \pi r (r+L)$$

by setting $V$ to my supply's max voltage ($30V$),  $\rho$ to the ohms/meter of my wire (~$13.43$), $\varepsilon$ to the emissitivity of nichrome (~0.88), $T$ to the max operating temperature of nichrome ($1473.15$ K to account for loss), and $r$ to my wire's radius ($0.16 \cdot 10^{-3}$ meters) I could solve for the unknown length of the wire, $L$.

finding $L$ around $0.532$ meters (or $21$ inches), I calculated it would draw around $4.2$ Amps of current, meaning I could put two 21-inch strips in parallel without exceeding the $10$A limit of my power supply. This is the arrangement of wire I have inside the burnout oven.

Ideally, I would like a formula to determine the inside temp given *any* applied voltage and current, but if that is not practical, I would prefer that (using the values above) someone could determine the maximum *attainable* internal temperature, which would let me know the upper bounds of temperature for my burnout oven, from which I can use a kiln thermometer to adjust the voltage/current to a desired temperature below that. (Originally posted on [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/753643/calculate-temperature-of-surroundings-given-heat-source))

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unless the oven is operating in vacuum, the heat loses will be also caused by forced convection of surrounding air, so you should take that into account. Also, outside surface of the oven should not be hot enough to have significant radiation loses.